# My sql error in Java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets

Im trying to learn simple database connections with Java servlets. My code is supposed to take form data, check for table and create if not created, add the data to table, check if delete checkbox is selected and if so, delete table and finally return to index page.

I got an error message in glassfish (and its somehow in french, the language is set for english);

```
Info:   tietokantaPerusteet was successfully deployed in 2 050 milliseconds.
Info:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe près de '' à la ligne 6
Info:   Virhe: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe près de ' , )' à la ligne 1
Warning:   The web application [/LoginServletMaven] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Here are my servlets.

Handler servlet:

```
public class tilausServlet extends HttpServlet {

tietokantaYhteysJava myconnection = new tietokantaYhteysJava();
String tiedot02 = null;
String tiedot03 = null;
String tiedot04 = null;
String poista = null;

private void readFormData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException {
    tiedot02 = request.getParameter("tiedot02");
    tiedot03 = request.getParameter("tiedot03");
    tiedot04 = request.getParameter("tiedot04");

    if(request.getParameter("poista")!=null){

        myconnection.poistaTaulu();

    }

}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    myconnection.initDatabaseConnection();
    readFormData(request, response);
    boolean result = false;
    PrintWriter temp = response.getWriter();
    try {
        result = myconnection.writeToDB(tiedot02, tiedot03, tiedot04, request);
        if (result==true){                                
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
        else{
            temp.println("Tulostus, jos tietokantakirjoitus palauttaa arvon: False");
        }


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(tilausServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(tilausServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Database connection servlet:

```
public class tietokantaYhteysJava {
   HttpServletResponse commonResponse = null;
   HttpServletRequest commonRequest = null;
   PrintWriter commonOut =null;

   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/kanta01";

   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "";
   private Statement stmt = null;
   private Connection conn = null;


   public Statement getstmt(){
       if(stmt==null){
          initDatabaseConnection();
          return this.stmt;
       }       
       return this.stmt;
   }
   public Connection getconn(){
       return this.conn;
   }

    protected void initDatabaseConnection(){

        try{
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiedot` (" +
            "  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n" +
            "  `tiedot02` text NOT NULL,\n" +
            "  `tiedot03` text NOT NULL,\n" +
            "  `tiedot04` text NOT NULL,\n" +
            "  `aikaleima` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n" +
            "  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)"; 

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            System.out.println("Taulu luotu");

            if (conn.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("yhteys ei onnistunut");
            }else{
                System.out.println("yhteys onnistui");
            }          
        }
        catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException se){
            System.out.println(se.toString());
        }

   }

    public void poistaTaulu() throws SQLException{

        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql3 = "DROP TABLE tiedot";

        stmt.executeUpdate(sql3);

    }

    protected boolean writeToDB(String tiedot02, String tiedot03, String tiedot04, HttpServletRequest request) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        try{

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql2 = "insert into tiedot (tiedot02, tiedot03, tiedot04) values ("+tiedot02+", "+tiedot03+", "+tiedot04+")";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);

            System.out.println("Tiedot lisätty");                       
            return true;                      

        }catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Virhe: "+ex.toString());
            return false;
        } 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in insert statement i.e. you are missing quotes for your string fields:

```
String sql2 = "insert into tiedot (tiedot02, tiedot03, tiedot04) values ("+tiedot02+", "+tiedot03+", "+tiedot04+")";
```

Should be:

```
String sql2 = "insert into tiedot (tiedot02, tiedot03, tiedot04) values ('"+tiedot02+"', '"+tiedot03+"', '"+tiedot04+"')";
                                                                         ^            ^   ^            ^  ^            ^
```

In order to avoid this quote issue, you should consider using PreparedStatement which will avoid you from SQL injection vulnerability.